# xe sr-create type=ext results in backend failure

Tags: xen, debian

I'm trying to create an ext based storage repository:

```
xe sr-create content-type="local SR" \
   host-uuid=c7030a1f-15e3-7e7d-2932-b30200a15917 type=ext \
   device-config-device=/dev/sdb1 \
   shared=false name-label="Local File SR"
```

Results in:

```
There was an SR backend failure.
status: non-zero exit
stdout:
stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/xcp/sm/EXTSR", line 320, in <module>
    SRCommand.run(EXTSR, DRIVER_INFO)
  File "/usr/lib/xcp/sm/SRCommand.py", line 263, in run
    ret = cmd.run(sr)
  File "/usr/lib/xcp/sm/SRCommand.py", line 94, in run
    return self._run_locked(sr)
  File "/usr/lib/xcp/sm/SRCommand.py", line 131, in _run_locked
    return self._run(sr, target)
  File "/usr/lib/xcp/sm/SRCommand.py", line 214, in _run
    return sr.create(self.params['sr_uuid'], long(self.params['args'][0]))
  File "/usr/lib/xcp/sm/EXTSR", line 225, in create
    util.pread2(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/xcp/sm/util.py", line 177, in pread2
    return pread(cmdlist, quiet = quiet)
  File "/usr/lib/xcp/sm/util.py", line 164, in pread
    (rc,stdout,stderr) = doexec(cmdlist_for_exec)
  File "/usr/lib/xcp/sm/util.py", line 129, in doexec
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=Tru
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing util.py

```
vi /usr/lib/xcp/sm/util.py
```

and adding a print debug output statement:

```
def doexec(args, inputtext=None):
    """Execute a subprocess, then return its return code, stdout and stderr"""
    print ', '.join(args)  #  Added print statement for debugging
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
    (stdout,stderr) = proc.communicate(inputtext)
    rc = proc.returncode
    return (rc,stdout,stderr)
```

returned this output when running the sr-create command:

```
stdout: sginfo, -s, /dev/sdb1
/lib/udev/scsi_id, -g, -s, /block/sdb
/sbin/vgs, XSLocalEXT-0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a
dd, if=/dev/zero, of=/dev/sdb1, bs=1M, count=100, oflag=direct
/sbin/pvs, /dev/sdb1
pvcreate, --metadatasize, 10M, /dev/sdb1
vgcreate, XSLocalEXT-0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a, /dev/sdb1
/sbin/lvdisplay, /dev/XSLocalEXT-0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a/0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a
/sbin/vgs, --noheadings, --nosuffix, --units, b, XSLocalEXT-0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a
lvcreate, -n, 0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a, -L, 1012, XSLocalEXT-0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a
lvchange, -ay, /dev/XSLocalEXT-0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a/0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a
mkfs.ext3, -F, /dev/XSLocalEXT-0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a/0cee01cd-3f10-9c28-8a0f-dec270e7f37a
/lib/udev/scsi_id, -g, -s, /block/sdb
```

From this I could see that lvm tools are being used by `sr-create`.

---

**Problem Solved**

These tools were missing on my system.  Installing `apt-get install lvm2` resolved the issue for me.